# Interface Photoshop size for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, interface, size, photoshop

I am building an iPhone app interface and I know the dpi has to be 163, but when it comes to the size of the file, I was looking through all the recommendations and found 2 different answers...

Does anyone know what size should i set the Photoshop file at? The answers I have so far are:

1. "The screen on the iPhone is 480×320, minus the 20-pixel status bar (making a 460×320 working screen size). The screen shots on the App Store should not include the status bar."
2. "400 x 320 or
   960 x 640 (iPhone 4)
   You must also consider the landscape mode (320 x 400 and 640 x 960)"

I would really appreciate the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can forget about DPI, the resolution is what is important for you.
So the answer is... 
**320 x 480 pixels for iPhone - iPhone 3GS** (and iPod Touch, first -> third gen)
**640 x 960 pixels for iPhone 4 and iPod Touch 4th gen**

This is for full screen apps. This will help you a lot, when designing UIs for iDevices.
**SD resolution** ([link](http://teehanlax.com/s3.php?path=files/iPhone_GUI_PSD_4.psd.zip))
**Retina, HD resolution** ([link](http://teehanlax.com/s3.php?path=files/iPhone_4_GUI_PSD_Retina_Display.zip))

That's it...

Comment: These numbers are only for full screen "immersive" apps that hide the status bar.

Comment: The 4th gen iPod Touch is also 960x640.

Comment: Information updated, and links to SD and HD GUI kits have just been added.

Comment: Thanks Andreyco! Now, although this one I am doing is for iPhone 3, can i build it 640 x 960 (for iPhone 4) and then downsize it? This way, I wouldn't have to do another one when i'll do the iPhone 4 app

Comment: Sure you can :) While I were creating GUI for our iPhone app, I did it all in "HD" (640 x 960 pixels). Then I just downsized them for older iDevices ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Designing an app, you just need to use the right resolution.

So it is display resolution - top bar:

**640x920** (retina without the top bar)

**320x460** (iphone up to 3gs)

Answer (score 0):

The Official Answer is in Apple's iTunes Connect Developer Guide, which you can download from iTunes Connect after logging in.